# Changing the format of a Datetime object in a DataRow element

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ms-access

I have created a DataRow array: OBrienData from a data table build from a access database. I want to map its contents to another DataRow array NewClientData which will eventually be mapped to a mssql Database. PLease do not point out that there is other ways to map from Access to Mssql as i am doing this as an exercise. Everthing goes ok until i start mapping Datetime objects. I got an sql overflow error. When i looked i saw the format of the datetime object from access is different to what i required for the mssql database.

```
string dateString,format="u";                                                                     
NewCaseData[i]["Date_Opened"] = DateTime.ParseExact(OBrienData[z]["Date opened"].ToString(), format,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
NewCaseData[i]["Date_Closed"] = String.Format("{0:u}", OBrienData[z]["Date closed"]);
```

So i tried the above code. ParseExact gaves a error: 'string not valid' and string.format
makes no change at all?!

Comment: What is the type of `OBrienData[z]["Date opened"]`? If it's already a `DateTime` (and I'd hope it would be) you shouldn't go via string conversions at all. Basically, try to keep everything in DateTime rather than performing any conversions. Note that a `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a "format" - it's just the date/time, and how it's converted to a string by the `ToString` method is a different matter.

Comment: If `OBrienData[z]` is `DataRow`, then `OBrienData[z]["Date opened"]` is `object`. The instance behind this `object` is likely already `DateTime`. Try `System.Convert.ToDateTime` instead of `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: OBrienData[z]["Date opened"] is already a datetime and i have to convert it to string to use it in DateTime.ParseExact. To be honest i should not have to use it, i though string.format or something simpler should work?

Comment: why do you have to use `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally getting a sql overflow error. When i checked the data in the ms Database i found some of the data corrupted , null etc. So i used the try parse method in post : 7054782
to validate each value and copy over as normal or set to datetime.now or dbnull value.